# First argument is not an open RODBC channel

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I am connecting to an Oracle database via DNS (set up the connection on the tnsnames.ora with the name "database").

I am able to succesfully run the following code:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                  "database",
                  UID = "user",
                  PWD = "password",
                  trusted_connection = TRUE)
```

I am also able to succesfully list all the tables in the database via:

```
list <- dbListTables(con)
View(list)
```

However, when I run:

```
results <- sqlQuery(channel = con, query = "select * from myschemaname.table")
```

I get the error:

```
Error in sqlQuery(channel = con, query = "select * from myschemaname.table") : 
          first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

I have owner privileges and I am also able to update Excel Spreadsheets connected to this database via ODBC. 
If it's of any use, here's the output of str(con)

```
str(con)
Formal class 'Oracle' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 4 slots
  ..@ ptr     :<externalptr> 
  ..@ quote   : chr "\""
  ..@ info    :List of 13
  .. ..$ dbname               : chr ""
  .. ..$ dbms.name            : chr "Oracle"
  .. ..$ db.version           : chr "11.02.0040"
  .. ..$ username             : chr "user"
  .. ..$ host                 : chr ""
  .. ..$ port                 : chr ""
  .. ..$ sourcename           : chr "database"
  .. ..$ servername           : chr "database"
  .. ..$ drivername           : chr "SQORA32.DLL"
  .. ..$ odbc.version         : chr "03.80.0000"
  .. ..$ driver.version       : chr "11.02.0001"
  .. ..$ odbcdriver.version   : chr "03.52"
  .. ..$ supports.transactions: logi TRUE
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "Oracle" "driver_info" "list"
  ..@ encoding: chr ""
```

Comment: `sqlQuery` is from the `RODBC` package. Maybe you need the `ODBC::`-equivalent of `RODBC::sqlQuery()` to use your `DBI::dbConnect()` connection?

Comment: That's it, thank you so much! I'm now successfully using con <- odbcConnect("database", uid = "user", pwd = "password") to use RODBC functions. I'm new to stackoverflow, so do I have to write a final answer, or is it up to you? =)

Comment: I'll formulate an answer as soon I have time :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `RODBC::sqlQuery()` for a connection created with `DBI::dbConnect()`. Either use `DBI::dbGetQuery()` with `DBI::dbConnect()` or create a connection with `RODBC::odbcConnect()`, and use `RODBC::sqlQuery()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another context, but the same error:
If the table of your DB consists of numerics, you first of all have to load an object (nameofyourtable) of class xts:

```
    >library(RODBC)
    >library(DMwR)
    >library(xts)
    >data(nameofyourtable)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had something like this connecting to a SQL Server database. In the end I had to change the Trusted_Connection=TRUE to Trusted_Connection=Yes...